# Creating grouped dynamic rows with JSON result using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JSON request that returns a result as follows:

```
[
{"ID":"57","BookName":"Title1","AuthorID":"2" "AuthorName":"Paul"}
{"ID":"57","BookName":"Title1","AuthorID":"3" "AuthorName":"Mark"},
{"ID":"58","BookName":"Title2","AuthorID":"4" "AuthorName":"Bob"},
{"ID":"58","BookName":"Title2","AuthorID":"5" "AuthorName":"John"},
{"ID":"58","BookName":"Title2","AuthorID":"6" "AuthorName":"Chris"}
]
```

What I want to accomplish is the following HTML output. Where for each unique ID a new `div` with the unique authors are created. When a new ID is identified a new table row is created and the new author names are added within it as new divs.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>ID: 57</td>
    <td>BookName: Title1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="author">
            AuthorID : 2 Author Name: Paul
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            AuthorID : 3 Author Name: Mark
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ID: 58</td>
    <td>BookName: Title2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="author">
            AuthorID : 4 Author Name: Bob
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            AuthorID : 5 Author Name: John
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            AuthorID : 6 Author Name: Chris
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery code with some pseudo logic in it:

```
$.getJSON(fullurl, function(json) {
    var bookid = '';
    $.each(json, function(i,d) {
        if(d.ID!= bookid){
            make new book row
            bookid= d.ID
         }
        else 
            use same row to show author div
         }
     }//end foreach
```

Can someone help me understand how I can do this?

Comment: Add your stuff to JSFiddle.net so we do not have to

Comment: `$("<div/>", {class:"author"}).html("AuthorID:"+d.AuthorID+" Author Name:"+d.AuthorName).appendTo(cell)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not able to have the JSON output in a structure you can work with, you'll have to manipulate it to be so.  You want to group authors by books.

```
var books = {};
$.each(json, function () {
    if (!books.hasOwnProperty(this.ID)) {
        books[this.ID] = {
            "ID": this.ID,
            "BookName": this.BookName,
            "authors": []
        };
    }
    books[this.ID].authors.push({"AuthorID": this.AuthorID, "AuthorName":
        this.AuthorName});
});
```

It should be relatively easy to loop over `books`, which has the desired structure, and append the table rows as you have explained above.

http://jsfiddle.net/rAYFZ/